# Kit for beginners

Tags: hardware

I discovered the raspberry pi recently from an article and I have read quite a lot about it even went through some tutorials. I want to order a raspberry pi board. I would like to enquire about other items I should include along with the board to make up a beginners kit or if there are any readily prepared kits for learning, and where can I purchase it. A link in the UK is most preferred.

Comment: You have any specific projects in mind? have you ever used linux before? There are many kits, it might be good if you let us know what you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've never used linux before, I used to windows. I also intend to build a security door with wireless internet capabilities for live streaming of security cam and getting other data from the internet as my first project.

 FYI, I'm an accomplished web and native software developer. I'm only new to the whole device development thingy. Thanks

Comment: Very good question! As beginner you want to know, what is possible and expect to get an overview of a modular concept of available kits and their capabilities, like when you enter a McDonald's, studied the offered menus and intent to order WITHOUT 7 callbacks or a response like "You can try the chicken and if you don't like it, next time you can try the other menu", which would imply a waste of time and money.

Answer (score 3):

user236012's answer *is* helpful, but as Kozuch pointed out, having a list of components to get would be very helpful for an absolute beginner.

I thought I'd just point out that there is a kit, known as the CamJam EduKit, released by Jamie Mann, of The Pi Hut, and Mike Horne, a CamJam organizer, that comes with LEDs, resistors, jumper wires, a button, a breadboard, and a buzzer.

[image: camjam edukit]

All of these come packaged up in a nice little box that you [can order from The Pi Hut](http://thepihut.com/products/camjam-edukit) for £5.00 (inc. VAT), €6.26 (inc. VAT), or $8.39.

There are also several free (6 currently, 8 planned) worksheets/projects that you can do with your Pi and the CamJam EduKit that you [can download from the CamJam EduKit page](http://camjam.me/camjam/?page_id=236) on the CamJam site.

Hope this helped some!

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best way to start is to simply buy some leds, buttons, wires, a bunch of resistors and a breadboard. They're cheap and you can them buy anywhere (on- and offline). Once you're familiar with the pi and have ideas for interesting projects, you can buy additional stuff. I bought my first pi along with the piface, which is a shield with some buttons and leds, but I wouldn't remommend that, it's just too expensive compared to the single components.

Comment: Yes but WHAT leds, buttons, wires, and resistors? A real beginner (including myself) is absolutely out of the game at first. Links to concrete items with specs would be very helpful. Links to eBay items from within European Union would be even better :).

Comment: @Kozuch Links are frowned upon on SE. The answer is appropriate. There are 100's of tutorials online to get him/her started. Google is their friend.